# Why does HTTP Authorization Manager only work if HTTP Request implementation is HTTPClient3.1?

Tags: jmeter

I have configured the HTTP Authorization Manager, but for some reason it only logs in if HTTPClient3.1 is selected as the implementation of my HTTP Request. Furthermore it does not seem like JMeter sends the information at all if Java or HTTPClient4 is selected. 
I'd like to know why that is the case. 
Is it possible to change the configuration in one of the .properties files to get it to work with HTTPClient4? Especially since HTTPCLient3.1 is no longer being developed, and support for this may be dropped in a future JMeter release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of JMeter as of 2.13 version, see:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57242

Java Implementation does not support this.

Rest assured HttpClient 3.1 will not be dropped soon from JMeter.